# Uso da palavra "mitra" para descrever jovens

Tags: etimologia, português-europeu, uso-de-palavras, girias

Se virmos no dicionário a palavra ***mitra*** tem vários significados.
Um dos usos de mitra é para denominar jovens com determinadas características e comportamentos que o dicionário priberam descreve da seguinte forma:

> 10. [Portugal, Informal, Depreciativo]  Jovem urbano, geralmente associado às camadas sociais mais desfavorecidas, de comportamento ruidoso, desrespeitoso, ameaçador ou violento e que tem gostos considerados vulgares
>
>     *Ver* [*"mitra", in Dicionário Priberam.*](https://dicionario.priberam.org/mitra)

Eu gostava de saber a história do uso da palavra neste sentido. Em algum momento do séc.XX caiu em desuso ou voltou a entrar em moda? O sentido referido acima é contemporâneo ou veio de tempos antigos?

Comment: Mais outra que eu não conhecia. De acordo com o Priberam, *mitra* tem significados algo depreciativos em Lisboa, Porto e Brasil, mas todos diferentes! Traçar a evolução destas gírias é muitas vezes tarefa impossível. O Dicionário da Sociedade da Língua Portuguesa (1964) regista apenas a gíria brasileira. Tem *mandar à mitra* ('mandar bugiar, à fava') e observa de seguida que parte do palácio da Mitra (Loures?) é usado como asilo municipal.

Comment: @Jacinto um sentido que os dicionários ainda não registam mas tornou-se comum recentmente e parece estar para ficar. *"A Mitra"* (no feminino) passou a ser sinónimo do reformatório e das prisões-escola.

Comment: Como diz o @Jacinto, esse uso de mitra é do centro, no norte chama-se a isso um guna. No norte, "mitra" é o substantivo relativo a mitrar: pedir coisas dadas sem a outra pessoa ter expectativa de retorno do "favor", "[impôr] a sua presença ou companhia, [ir] a eventos ou actividades sem ter sido convidado", etc. O sentido primário que eu reconheço de "mitrar" é o do verbo "to bum": «to obtain by asking or begging (=cadge): bum a cigarette» https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cadge

Comment: @ANevesthinksSEisevil "Guna" é pouco representativo, a palavra sugere vir do Inglês "Goon". Incluindo no Porto o *mitra* é reconhecido de Faro a Bragança, e da Figueira à Guarda. Só ouvi essa palavra aos portuenses, em jeito distinção para corrigir e fazer uma piada (função semelhante ao *totil*). Quanto ao *mitra* em verbo que leva ao substantivo, tu próprio dizes o significado ser muito próximo. Falta também saber se o *guna* foi uma palavra alternativa que encontraram aquando à massificação do *mitra*, só conheço o uso do *guna* como sendo um década posterior a toda a gente dizer *mitra*.

Comment: Discordo da maior parte disso, bad_coder, no que toca ao Porto ou talvez até à região norte. "Mitra" é um false-friend por cá; não acredito que seja reconhecido com o mesmo sentido no Porto que no resto do país; e guna é *pelo menos* de há 50 anos ("andar à guna"), por isso deve predatar qualquer data que um programador tenha vivido. (Desde [casas de vinho do Porto do século 16](http://www.croftport.com/pt/sobre-a-croft/croft-hoje/) até à mais antiga aliança do mundo, não faltam motivos históricos para anglicismos portuenses.)

Comment: @ANevesthinksSEisevil Éh pá, se me dizes que *"o guna"* já era usado há 50 anos arranja uma ou duas fontes e por favor converte isso em resposta. Eu adorava ver isso, e embora a palavra seja differente está intimamente relacionado. Era uma pena deixar passar sem assinalar.

Comment: @ANevesthinksSEisevil O *"andar à guna"* só dá [435 hits no goole](https://www.google.com/search?q="andar+à+guna") se procurarmos "à guna" dá [3450 hits no google](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22andar+%C3%A0+guna%22). O resultado mais antigo é de 2007, um blog no sapo...No conjunto acho estes registos todos muito pouco significativos. Coincide a estreia do termo na internet com o auge *"do mitra"* dos incontáveis festivais de música, e nova delinquência da época...

Comment: Bad-coder e @ANeves, encontrei pessoal a fazer distinções entre [*mitra* e *guna*](https://odeiovos.blogs.sapo.pt/9138.html) já em 2004.

Comment: "Andar à guna" está [no Priberam](https://dicionario.priberam.org/andar%20%C3%A0%20guna). Serve como fonte? Sendo "sobretudo nos elétricos", parece-me claro que é pelo menos do tempo dos elétricos - anterior a 2000. Procurar referências online para **calão** anterior à internet é ingrato e pouco proveitoso. As páginas anteriores a... digamos 2000, que teriam calão, entretanto expiraram. Não se vai encontrar nada exceto livros digitalizados ou vídeos. Tudo o resto (fórums, BBS, mailing lists) vai ter estado em comunidades que não se mantiveram por 20 anos, e desapareceram da internet.

Comment: Bad-coder e @ANeves, no Google Books têm coisas mais antigas: em 1983, [andava à guna nos eléctricos](https://books.google.pt/books?id=3alIAAAAYAAJ&q=%22andava+%C3%A0+guna%22&dq=%22andava+%C3%A0+guna%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjJg621g4v1AhUNCxoKHWexD-oQ6AF6BAgCEAI) (*Centro histórico do Porto*). Quando é que acabaram os elétricos no Porto?

Comment: @Jacinto, tecnicamente os elétricos nunca acabaram; converteram-se em meio de transporte turístico. (Ainda se vê andar à guna hoje em dia, mas raramente.) Pelos anos 2000 já não se usavam elétricos em mais do que meia dúzia de linhas - lembro-me dum que percorria a Avenida da Boavista, do que seguia a marginal do rio (acho que é o único em serviço no presente), e acho que também havia ainda um na zona do Carmo/Clérigos.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Segundo Susana Durão ([*Patrulha de Proximidade: Uma Etnografia da Polícia em Lisboa*, ISCTE, 2006)](https://repositorio.iscte-iul.pt/bitstream/10071/274/4/Patrulha_e_Proximidade_pdf.pdf), na gíria da polícia lisboeta já no princípio deste século, o termo ***mitra*** era usado “em relação aos pequenos delinquentes de rua, sobretudo para os pequenos traficantes de drogas” (p. 86); o termo tinha a sua origem no Albergue da Mitra, uma instituição criada “durante os primeiros anos do Estado Novo para recolher e manter em reclusão os mendigos da rua” (p. 237).

O termo já estava em uso na polícia em 2001. Numa entrevista de março desse ano, um agente relata que ficou pouco satisfeito quando foi trabalhar na área do trânsito, porque (negrito meu) “[c]omo muitos outros o que eu queria era andar **à caça dos *mitras***” (p. 272). Também já era usado entre os seguranças do Metropolitano de Lisboa. Num [artigo de 8-12-2001 no *Público*](https://www.publico.pt/2001/12/08/jornal/os-locais-de-lisboa-onde-o-crime-acontece-165109) um segurança diz:

> "De vez em quando aparecem aí uns ‘mitras’, como a gente lhes chama, a palmar umas sandes nas lojas ou umas carteiras às velhinhas

O Albergue da Mitra — oficialmente, o Albergue Distrital de Mendicidade de Lisboa — foi, segundo este [artigo de 10-9-2014 no *Público*](https://www.publico.pt/2014/09/10/local/noticia/misericordia-investe-5-milhoes-de-euros-para-abrir-as-portas-da-mitra-aos-lisboetas-1669217), criado em 1933 no antigo Palácio da Mitra, construído em finais do século XVII para residência dos prelados de Lisboa. O palácio tomou o seu nome da [*mitra* (Priberam)](https://dicionario.priberam.org/mitra), um barrete usado por bispos, arcebispos e cardeais em cerimónias importantes.

Segundo o [artigo](https://www.publico.pt/2014/09/10/local/noticia/misericordia-investe-5-milhoes-de-euros-para-abrir-as-portas-da-mitra-aos-lisboetas-1669217), o Albergue “tornou-se uma espécie de ‘prisão’” e originou em Lisboa as expressões “‘ir para a Mitra’, usada por vezes como ameaça, ou até insulto”, e “‘vai para a Mitra’ [que] era usada como sinónimo de ‘não me chateies’”. Já em 1964, O *Dicionário da Sociedade de Língua Portuguesa* regista *ir, mandar à Mitra* como “eufemismo plebeu de Lisboa”.

Da tese de Susana Durão fico com a ideia que *mitra* antes de referir ’delinquentes’ pudesse ter referido “os sem-abrigo, os vadios e as prostitutas”. Mas o texto não é completamente claro para mim, portanto aqui fica, para cada um tirar as suas conclusões (p. 237-8):

> O termo tem uma origem histórica particular na realidade portuguesa […] o antigo Albergue da Mitra, criado durante os primeiros anos do Estado Novo para recolher e manter em reclusão os mendigos da rua; […] A Mitra foi encerrada nos anos 80 mas o termo e os sentidos estigmatizantes que traduziam persistiram. Os sentidos em uso revelam, todavia, a mudança do foco da patrulha nas últimas décadas: os patrulheiros começaram a controlar cada vez menos os “sujeitos da mendigagem” e a dar cada vez mais atenção aos complexos universos da droga, da traficância, dos esquemas, dos furtos e de todas as actividades ilícitas de rua. Da perspectiva policial de hoje os verdadeiros *senhores das ruas* são estes novos *mitras* e já não os sem-abrigo, os vadios e as prostitutas.

Fora do ambiente policial e segurança privada, a primeira referência aos *mitras* que encontrei foi no [bog *Odeio-vos* de 29-8-2004](https://odeiovos.blogs.sapo.pt/9138.html). São descritos, já não como delinquentes, mas como jovens imbecis, rudes, e vestidos de maneira peculiar. Duas semanas depois, uma reposta diz que a descrição corresponde aos “gunas”, e que o mitras são aqueles que andam sempre à pala de qualquer coisa. Possivelmente eram já as diferenças terminológicas entre Lisboa e Porto.

---

### Curiosamente, no Brasil

[***Mitra*** (Michaelis)](https://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno-portugues/busca/portugues-brasileiro/mitra/) pode significar:

> **1** Reg. (S.) Que ou aquele que tem esperteza ou sagacidade; esperto, finório, mitrado.
> **2** Reg. (S.) Diz-se de ou animal manhoso.

Isto poderá vir de *mitrado*, que segundo o Dicionário da Sociedade de Língua Portuguesa (1964) significa: “[q]ue tem mitra *ou* o direito de a usar” e “[s]ábio, sagaz como um bispo”.